# Null sets and discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Which subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of Lebesgue-measure zero occur as the sets of points of discontinuity for a function $f$: $\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The Lebesque criterion for Riemannian integrability in your case might be relevant. Recall that a bounded function $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the
set of points on which f is discontinuous, is a set of measure zero. [link to the theorem and other](http://www.math.unm.edu/~crisp/courses/math402/spring15/Abraham.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A $F_\sigma$ set is a set which can be written as a countable union of closed sets. For a metric space $M$ and a function $f : M \to M$, the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ is an $F_\sigma$ set. In the case $M=\mathbb{R}$ the converse is true: any $F_\sigma$ set is the set of points of discontinuity of some function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.